# Where can I find Sefer Hatishbi with Hagahot Ragle Mevaser?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, books-generally

I am trying to locate, electronically or otherwise, a copy of Sefer Hatishbi with Hagahot Ragle Mevaser, for purchase or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may  want to check out [this edition](http://www.virtualgeula.com/Stock/Books/Show/10570) which contains the hagahot Ragle Mevaser (among others). See it [inside for details](http://www.virtualgeula.com/10500/10570.pdf).